# c++ for_each process two containers parallel

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, lambda

i want to process 2 containers that are related somehow and i want to process them element wise with each other.

simple example:
one container contains some kind of sums and another container of equal length contains numbers that have to be subtracted from that sum.

```
std::vector<int> s = {20,56,7,34,234,23,54};
std::vector<int> m = {1,3,5,2,3,5,6};

for(int i=0; i<s.size();++i){
  s[i] -= m[i];
}
```

is there a more elegant way to achieve that e.g. using for_each?

Comment: You could have an `iterator` for the "other" vector. But I really don't see the point, the code you've posted is fine (except for range checks, of course).

Comment: Your solution is elegant already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use a std algorithm for this, you can go with transform:

```
std::transform(begin(s),end(s),begin(m),begin(s),yourfunc);
```

where `yourfunc` takes the elements from s and m and returns the desired modification into s (or any other container of your choice).

```
auto yourfunc = [](int ms, int mm){return ms-mm;};
```

Comment: thanks i did not knew transform.  but you all may be right that this may not increase readability at all. btw: std::minus could be used as yourfunc.